# Linking an image by an image in jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, image, mobile, jquery-mobile, linker

I'm not experienced with jQuery mobile, but I want to link in an image to the same image but a thumbnail, like this:

```
<a href="image.jpg" class="image" data-rel="dialog"><img class="ui-li-thumb" src="image.jpg"/>
```

I have read that I can put `rel="external"` as an attribute, but I lost the transition effect.

Comment: To clarify, you want to link a thumbnail to a larger version of the same image?

Comment: Exactly RonnieT, but i want to show it on a dialog, with some transition effect

Comment: Finally i decided to adapt an image gallery, concretly the "Photoswipe"

Comment: i have found another gallery that is better for me. It's called "idangerous swiper" ;)